# Ruby replace html fragments with specified links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath

I have a Rails Model with field "description" and other Model Person with field "title".
I want to add ability to replace all Person titles into description field to correct links
For example `John Smith` to `<a href='/person/1'>John Smith</a>`
Also I want to avoid tag  dupliation inside itself.
Of course person name could be an anchor of tag  in phrase, for example `<a href='any link'>Meet John Smith</a>` - that case of course should stay same.
And I want to make that action as button, which could be pressed any times with correct same result - when all single non A-anchor texts will be replaced with links.

How could I reach it? With xpath or regexp maybe?

Comment: Got what you want, but didn't get where do you want it? Do you want it when you generate your view?

Comment: Are you using link_to or raw ?

Comment: It could be just model method - I call it and transfer description field's Person titles into links to that person into website.
link_to and raw - both ways are ok